# Write the output of a program in 2 different files

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line, command

I have to exec a job on a server from remote in ssh.
This job (written in C++) print to the standard output. I have to pick the results and write to an output file (log_tests.txt). I do

```
nohup ./my_executable_name > log_tests.txt 2>&1 &
```

But I have to write some things to a file and others to a different file ( log_tests2.txt). I wan't directly write on the correct file from the source code because the places on the code that I should modify are about 200: however I could change cout to cerr if this was necessary for canalize the outputs on the 2 different files. Is there a way to do that?

(The server is with Unix, the source code is in C++11)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you redirect the other messages to cerr, the command would be `nohup ./my_executable_name > log_tests.txt 2> log_tests2.txt`. However, is it possible to recognize by some pattern what the message is about? If yes, one can use grep to select proper set of messages. On the other hand - if you can replace `cout` with `cerr`, why not replace `cout` with `streamout1` and `streamout2` with the latter ones being your own stream opened to write to a file.

Comment: Because in the print on cout and cerr you use output formattation (iomanip and other) that I don't if is equal with streamout1.... I'm trying your solution. No each message has  a pattern . Thus, no grep

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Yes it works. Thanks!

Comment: `std::cout` and `std::cerr` are instances of `std::ostream`. File stream is instance of `std::ofstream` which inherits after `std::ostream`. So, all yours iomanips and others shall be safe.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Ok. But in this way I have to modify all 200 places on the source code, instead with your first solution I have to modify 27 places alone (where I replace cout with cerr, instead the cout's remain the same)

Comment: I understand. However, if you decide to write to files directly - for example, when you decide to have a third category of logs - you can use following command to replace all occurences of `std::cout` with, for example, `streamout1`: `sed -i.orig -e 's/std::cout/streamout1/g' *.cpp`.

Comment: If you code writes to `std::cout` and you want to redirect that to a file you *can* change `std::cout`'s `rdbuf()` to that of an `std::ofstream`. Also, changing "all 200" places may be good idea: while the code is still tiny things are much easier to change.